# Какая максимальная и минимальная длина расширения файлов?

Tags: расширения

Сколько минимум и максимум символов может содержать расширение файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Некоторые операционные системы ограничивают длину расширения (например, DOS и OS / 2, до трех символов), в то время как другие (например, Unix) этого не делают. Некоторые операционные системы (например, RISC OS) не используют расширения имен файлов. Unix принимает разделительную точку в качестве юридического символа, но не дает ей особого признания на уровне ОС.

С учетом того что я не знаю про какую именно ОС вы спрашиваете, и исходя из того что на нашей планете подавляющее большинство сидит на Windows то я могу предположить что вы тоже пользуетесь этою операционной системой. Для Windows минимальной длиной расширения файла является один символ.

Надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос :)

[Первоисточник](https://superuser.com/questions/233294/what-are-the-practical-limits-on-file-extension-name-lengths)